# I want to make a loop which stucks user till the correct word entered, but when the correct word entered it doesn't show the proper output

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I want to make a loop which stucks user till the correct word entered, but when the correct word entered it doesn't show the proper output. Here what i have done

```
word = "High Sir"
        Letter = input("How is the Josh! \n")
        while Letter!= word:
            if Letter == word:
                Letter = ("Well Done! You are selected for next stage.")
            else:
                Letter = input("Bullshit, Enter Again\n")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not working because your condition for the loop is `while Letter != word` which means that you only enter the loop when `Letter` and `word` are NOT equal. Hence, when the user enters the correct word, `Letter` and `word` become equal and the loop condition fails which is why it does not enter the loop. You want something like this:

```py
required_word = "High Sir"

while True:
    user_word = input("How is the Josh! \n")
    
    if user_word == required_word :
        print("Well Done! You are selected for next stage.")
        break
    else:
        print("Incorrect word! Try again")
```